# Autoplay HTML5 video with Razorfish / Parallax-JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

Im using a video as a background on one page of a site that did autoplayed until I plugged in the Razorfish / Parallax-JS from https://github.com/razorfish/Parallax-JS/

I can still right click the background and see the play option but No matter what I do I cannot get the video to autoplay anymore. Someone asked a similar question on GitHub but no answer.

My Video tag opens like this...

```
<video id="video_background" preload="auto" muted="" volume="0" autoplay >
```

I have tried all the following and many different variations but no luck...

```
document.getElementById("video_background").setAttribute('autoplay', true);
$("#video_background")[0].load();
$("#video_background")[0].play();
$("#video_background").get(0).play();
$('#video_background').attr({'autoplay':'true'});
```

Every other part of the plugin is working so it would be great if I could find a solution.

Comment: For boolean values you should use `prop()` and not `attr()` in jQuery. Also note that `true` and `false` are invalid values for boolean attributes. Check out [w3c boolean attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute), and the other sub topics on the [video element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#the-video-element). Not sure if this solves anything, so I leave it as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<video id="video_background" autoplay loop muted preload="auto">
```

Comment: Would be nice if you explained *why* he should try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can work your way around it, by detecting page change and tell HTML5 player to play, when desired page is reached.

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){ 
if(document.URL.indexOf("#intel") >= 0){ 
    var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    v.play();
}
```

});